# Python MemoryError when appending a list

Tags: python, list, function

I've a small Python (2.7.10) script, which you can see below.

```
def numbers_calc(max_num, num_step):
    """Returns every number from 0 to max_num with num_step as step."""
    n = 0
    l = []

    while n < max_num + 1:
        l.append(n)
        n += n * num_step

    return l

n_l = []
n_l.append(numbers_calc(25, 1))

print "Here are the numbers."
print n_l
```

The function `numbers_calc` is meant to take all the given args, form a list, and populate it with numbers (with `num_step` as the step when calculating) before it reaches `max_num + 1`. The script then does `return` it's local list named `l`.

However, every time I run the script, I encounter `MemoryError`. Here's what Python returned when I ran the script:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "num.py", line 13, in <module>
    n_l.append(numbers_calc(25, 1))
  File "ex33.py", line 7, in numbers_calc
    l.extend(i)
MemoryError
```

I tried looking it up, saw nothing helpful. I hope you can help me!

Comment: The traceback you provided doesn't actually match the code you provided. The traceback reference the line `l.extend(i)`, which doesn't exist in the code.

Comment: Your function sounds a lot like the built-in `range` function - have you considered using that directly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is in the line -

```
n += n * num_step
```

Here, you initialized `n` as `0` , and then you are multiplying `n` and `num_step` , whose result would always be `0` , and then adding it to `n` . So `n` always stays at `0` . If you are Try to loop from 0 to max_num+1 for every num_step, you should use `range()` function, Example -

```
def numbers_calc(max_num, num_step):
    """Returns every number from 0 to max_num with num_step as step."""
    l = []

    for i in range(0,max_num + 1,num_step):
        l.append(i)

    return l
```

Answer (score 2):

`n` starts at 0. `n += n * num_step` adds 0 to `n`. `n` never changes, and your loop keeps adding items to the list forever.

Cause `n` to change somehow.

Comment: Thanks. Really helped me!

Answer (score 1):

anything times `0` is always going to be `0` so you have an infinite loop setting`n = 0` set `n` to 1 initially:

```
def numbers_calc(max_num, num_step):
   """Returns every number from 0 to max_num with num_step as step."""
   n = 1
   l = []

   while n < max_num + 1:
       l.append(n)
       n += n * num_step
       print(n)
   return l

n_l = []
n_l.append(numbers_calc(25, 1))
```

Output:

```
[[1, 2, 4, 8, 16]]
```

If you want a list of number just use the return value:

```
nl = numbers_calc(25, 1)
```

Which will give you `[1, 2, 4, 8, 16]`

If you actually want *every number from 0 to max_num with num_step*  use `+=` not `*=` and leave `n` at `0`:

```
def numbers_calc(max_num, num_step):
       """Returns every number from 0 to max_num with num_step as step."""
       n = 0
       l = []   
       while n < max_num + 1:
           l.append(n)
           n += num_step
           print(n)    
       return l
```

Or simply return range with a step:

```
def numbers_calc(max_num, num_step):
       """Returns every number from 0 to max_num with num_step as step."""
       return  list(range(max_num + 1,num_step))
```

You should be aware that if the step is not a multiple of `max_num` then you are not going to get `max_num` i.e `numbers_calc(25, 2)` will go to `24` .

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everybody for helping! Didn't even realise I had math problems there. Thank you all! By the way, here's the final version of my script.

```
def numbers_calc(max_num, num_step):
    """Returns every number from 0 to max_num with num_step as step."""
    i = 0
    l = []

    while i < max_num + 1:
        l.append(i)
        i += num_step

    return l

n_l = numbers_calc(25, 5)

print "Here are the numbers."
print n_l
```